# Most efficient way to find the count of matches a string has against an array of words?

Tags: java

let's say I have a string

```
String test = "This is a test string and I have some stopwords in here";
```

and I want to see how many times the words in the array below match against my string

psudocode

```
array = a,and,the,them,they,I
```

so the answer would be "3"

just curious what the most efficient way to do that in java is?

Comment: Interesting question, let me see if I can come up with something better than the naive algorithm

Comment: What about repeats? Answers below read data into Sets, which would score 3 for "a and the" but only 1 for "a a a". Is that the desired behavior, or should both report 3?

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably store the words in the input into a HashSet and then iterate over the array and see if each word in the array is .contains in the set.

Here it is in code... the input is "[Around the world in 80 days](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/103)".

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final File     file;
        final String[] wordsToFind;

        file        = new File(argv[0]);
        wordsToFind = getWordsToFind(file);
        a(file, wordsToFind);
        b(file, wordsToFind);
        c(file, wordsToFind);
        d(file, wordsToFind);
    }

    // this just reads the file into the disk cache
    private static String[] getWordsToFind(final File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final Scanner     scanner;
        final Set<String> words;

        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        words   = new HashSet<String>();

        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            final String word;

            word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        return (words.toArray(new String[words.size()]));
    }

    // bad way, read intpo a list and then iterate over the list until you find a match
    private static void a(final File     file,
                          final String[] wordsToFind)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final long start;
        final long end;
        final long total;
        final Scanner      scanner;
        final List<String> words;
        int                matches;

        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        words   = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            final String word;

            word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        start = System.nanoTime();

        {
            matches = 0;

            for(final String wordToFind : wordsToFind)
            {
                for(final String word : words)
                {
                    if(word.equals(wordToFind))
                    {
                        matches++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(matches);
        }

        end   = System.nanoTime();
        total = end - start;
        System.out.println("a: " + total);
    }

    // slightly better way, read intpo a list and then iterate over the set (which reduces the number of things you progbably
    // have to read until you find a match), until you find a match
    private static void b(final File     file,
                          final String[] wordsToFind)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final long start;
        final long end;
        final long total;
        final Scanner     scanner;
        final Set<String> words;
        int               matches;

        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        words   = new HashSet<String>();

        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            final String word;

            word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        start = System.nanoTime();

        {
            matches = 0;

            for(final String wordToFind : wordsToFind)
            {
                for(final String word : words)
                {
                    if(word.equals(wordToFind))
                    {
                        matches++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(matches);
        }

        end   = System.nanoTime();
        total = end - start;
        System.out.println("b: " + total);
    }

    // my way
    private static void c(final File     file,
                          final String[] wordsToFind)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final long start;
        final long end;
        final long total;
        final Scanner     scanner;
        final Set<String> words;
        int               matches;

        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        words   = new HashSet<String>();

        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            final String word;

            word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        start = System.nanoTime();

        {
            matches = 0;

            for(final String wordToFind : wordsToFind)
            {
                if(words.contains(wordToFind))
                {
                    matches++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(matches);
        }

        end   = System.nanoTime();
        total = end - start;
        System.out.println("c: " + total);
    }

    // Nikita Rybak way
    private static void d(final File     file,
                          final String[] wordsToFind)
        throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final long start;
        final long end;
        final long total;
        final Scanner     scanner;
        final Set<String> words;
        int               matches;

        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        words   = new HashSet<String>();

        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            final String word;

            word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        start = System.nanoTime();

        {
            words.retainAll(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(wordsToFind)));
            matches = words.size();
            System.out.println(matches);
        }

        end   = System.nanoTime();
        total = end - start;
        System.out.println("d: " + total);
    }
}
```

results (after a few runs, each run is pretty much the same though):

```
12596
a: 2440699000
12596
b: 2531635000
12596
c: 4507000
12596
d: 5597000
```

If you modify it by adding "XXX" to each of the words in getWordsToFind (so no words are found) you get:

```
0
a: 7415291000
0
b: 4688973000
0
c: 2849000
0
d: 7981000
```

And, for completeness, I tried it just searching for the word "I", and the results are:

```
1
a: 235000
1
b: 351000
1
c: 75000
1
d: 10725000
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? Not sure about 'most efficient', but simple enough.

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("This is a test string and I have some stopwords in here".split("\\s")));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "and", "the", "them", "they", "I"));
s1.retainAll(s2);
System.out.println(s1.size());
```

Just intersection of two sets of words.

Answer (score 3):

the most efficient thing to do is sort both 'test' and 'array' and then iterate over both: n.log(n) + n

test -> ['a', 'and', 'have', 'here', in, is, ..., 'This']
array -> ['a', 'and', 'the', 'them', 'they', 'I']

array   test    matches
'a'     'a'     1
'a'     'and'   1
'and'   'and'   2
'and'   'have'  2
'the'   'here'  2
'the'   'in'    2
'the'   'is'    2
...

Comment: @Aircule it is, because both ordered arrays are traversed simultaneously. The only problem with this algorithm is that it's not so trivial to impliment :)

Comment: +1, but it's not the most efficient way. While here we have O(n log(n)), hash operations take constant time and thus goal can be achieved in O(n).

Comment: @Aircule not like that. you have two different indexes (i and j) and increase the one with smallest value: _if (a[i] <= b[j]) {++i} else {++j};_

Comment: Keep two pointers, one that keeps track of your position in "test" and one in "array", say i and j. Then you have a few conditions: if t[i] == a[j], add the word to your set, increment i and j. if t[i] > a[j], j++. else, i++. That way you can iterate through both the arrays in O(n) time.

Comment: @Nikita-Rybak Hashing sounds fun, but once you implement it you'll realize it is a huge bottleneck in the process. Even if you use a rolling hash.

Comment: @Aircule Don't know what's the rolling hash, but I've never heard any performance complaints about hashes. (not HashSet in particular, but idea in general) Hash is just an array, after all.

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation on Nikita's answer (up 1 for Nikita). If you use a List for s1, you get the number of occurrences (in case a word appears multiple times in the sentence).

```
List<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("This is a test string and I have some stopwords in here".split("\\s")));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "and", "the", "them", "they", "I"));
s1.retainAll(s2);
System.out.println(s1.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

store your strings in hashtable (HashMap of (String and Integer)) , then iterator over the text and increase the integer value for the matching word in hashtable . then iterator over hashtable and sum all integer values.